# Joining neutral of two ac power meters?

Tags: safety, neutral

I have single phase power in my area

I have two ac power meters connections at my home. Last night there was a windstorm and neutral cable of once AC meter got broken.

I had black out in half portion of my home that was connected to that meter whose wire was broken

Then I called to electricity office but long time passed but they didn't arrive.

Then I joined neutral wire to neutral wire of other AC power meter.

My question is that neutral wire shared/common in this way between two meters having separate phase wires

Is it safe?

Comment: If you need to ask then no. Call an electrician before you hurt yourself or someone else via electrocution and/or fire.

Comment: Good initiative :-) - BUT - **DYING WOULD BE EASY** || **IF** the circuits are both fed from the same phase **AND** the same utility transformer - **AND** if the current drawn is within the ratings of the wiring and fusing used **THEN**electrically this may not cause a problem. **BUT** the neutral connection that you made had mains voltage across it and you could easily die if you touched either the feed or the dead circuit while doing this. **AMD** the power company may be very unhappy with you doing this. If it does cause a problem you may be legally and financially liable.

Comment: The question seems to indicate that you have already made the connection. It that is the case, the power is restored to the previously dark area, you have already done the most unsafe part. There is still some risk that some portion of the neutral could be overloaded. You have supplied few details and avoided saying where you live. You now have comments and an answer from three continents. If something bad happens, be sure to return to the internet for legal and medical advice. Random people from random areas of the world will solve all of your problems instantly at no cost.

Answer (score 3):

Good initiative :-) - BUT -

**DYING WOULD BE EASY**

**IF** the circuits are both fed from the same phase
**AND** the same utility transformer -
**AND** if the current drawn is within the ratings of the wiring and fusing used     **THEN**electrically this may not cause a problem. Or may.

**BUT** the neutral connection that you made had mains voltage across it and you could easily die if you touched either the feed or the dead circuit while doing this.

**AND** the power company may be very unhappy with you doing this.
If it does cause a problem you may be legally and financially liable.